# Is it programmatically possible for Google to track the referrer URL of a Google Maps URL on a mobile browser that opens up a native app?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, mobile-safari, google-chrome-app

If you click on a Google Maps URL link (comgooglemaps://) on a website in Safari or Chrome on an Android or iOS device that opens up the native Google Maps App, is it possible for Google track the referring website that you clicked the link on?

For example: If you clicked on comgooglemaps://?q=Pizza&center=37.759748,-122.427135 from stackoverflow.com in Chrome or Safari on iOS or Android, this takes you to the Google Maps native app. Can Google track the referring site (stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible track the referring website so far.

Google Maps Application just only receive info in  the "comgooglemaps://" schemed url. The Google Maps URL scheme allows you to launch the Google Maps Application, and perform one of the following actions:searches, direction requests, and display map views with valid parameters in google document: [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

Unfortunately, there isn't an available parameter relate to referring website.

**UPDATE**: Discuss with:[the related answer in webmasters.stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55907/can-google-track-the-referring-url-from-their-google-maps-url-scheme-on-android)

1. As the related answer said, if you click a URL (comgooglemaps://) in a web page made by google, **maybe**, google will track the referrer url(such as with Google Analytics). If the assume is true, google track the referrer url in Browser, not in Maps App.
2. On the other hand, if you click a URL (comgooglemaps://) in a web page made by yourself, and you don't implement any Google Analytics function. In this way, it's impossible track the referring url by google.
3. If the launch action is between two apps, unless the departure implement Google Analytics function, nobody can track the referring url.

Comment: Good to know. I assume you're speaking in terms of a developer. Can Google itself track the referring website from this scenario?

Comment: @novicePrgrmr I think Google cann't. Beacuse the process of launching app by schemed URL is handled by iOS/Android system.The transferred info is clearly just a schemed URL.

Comment: Does this answer have any validity? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55907/can-google-track-the-referring-url-from-their-google-maps-url-scheme-on-android

Comment: Awesome, you don't know how great it is to hear this.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear from google privacy policy,If you logged into your google account and then click on any referrel url means goolge may able to track that.But read the privacy policy carefully **"we may automatically collect and store certain information in server logs"**

Privacy Policy

There are many different ways you can use our services – to search for and share information, to communicate with other people or to create new content. When you share information with us, for example by creating a **Google Account**, we can make those services even better – to show you more relevant search results and ads, to help you connect with people or to make sharing with others quicker and easier. As you use our services, we want you to be clear how we’re using information and the ways in which you can protect your privacy.

Our Privacy Policy explains:

- What information we collect and why we collect it.
- How we use that information.
- The choices we offer, including how to access and update
  information.

Log information

When you use our services or view content provided by Google, **we may automatically collect and store certain information inserver logs**. This may include:

- details of how you used our service, such as your search queries.
- telephony log information like your phone number, calling-party number, forwarding numbers, time and date of calls, duration of calls, SMS routing information and types of calls.
- Internet protocol address.
- device event information such as crashes, system activity, hardware settings, browser type, browser language, the date and time of your request and **referral URL**.
- cookies that may uniquely identify your browser or your Google Account.

For more details : https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/